# Try to using ajax form instead of form action (solve)

Tags: php, ajax, ajaxform

I would like to improve user experience at my website. So I try to change the form action ajax, and I has been try some tutorial but I still getting stuck.

I am using a php forum program/source code call `!Discuz` and it was from China. Below is my coding now.

In html.

```
<form method="post" id="jnfarm_pop" action="plugin.php?id=cc&do=shop">
<input type="hidden" name="shopsubmit" value="yes">
<!--first item-->
<input type="checkbox" name="jsid[1]" value="1">
<input type="number" style="width:3em;" name="qty[1]">
<!--second item-->
<input type="checkbox" name="jsid[2]" value="1">
<input type="number" style="width:3em;" name="qty[2]">
...continue 50 item
<button type="submit" class="layui-btn layui-btn-fluid" name="submitbutn">submit</button>
</form>
```

in `PHP`, file name `plugin.php`

```
<?php
if($_GET['id'] == 'cc'){
  if(submitcheck('shopsubmit')){ //core function in !Discuz 
    for($x=1;$x<=50;$x++){
      if($_GET['jsid'][$x] == '1'){
        $qty[$x] = intval($_GET['qty'][$x]);
        //process....
      }
    }
    showmessage('message here','redirectlink');//this is !Discuz program function and it is fine.
  }
}
?>
```

The above script is working fine while using `form action`, and redirect to my output page. If I would like to change to ajax, how do I adjust the below source code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function login() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",//? is it can use json? since my form data can get as array
                url: "plugin.php?id=cc&do=shop" ,//url
                data: $('#jnfarm_pop').serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    if (result.resultCode == 200) {
                        alert("SUCCESS");
                    }
                    ;
                },
                error : function() {
                    alert("ERROR");
                }
            });
        }
</script>
<form method="post" id="jnfarm_pop" action="plugin.php?id=cc&do=shop">
<input type="hidden" name="shopsubmit" value="yes">
<!--first item-->
<input type="checkbox" name="jsid[1]" value="1">
<input type="number" style="width:3em;" name="qty[1]">
<!--second item-->
<input type="checkbox" name="jsid[2]" value="1">
<input type="number" style="width:3em;" name="qty[2]">
...continue 50 item
<button type="submit" class="layui-btn layui-btn-fluid" name="submitbutn" onclick="login()">submit</button>
</form>
```

And is it have to adjust the `plugin.php` source code?

Updated, below is work for me, thanks fayis003.
`html` change the `<script></script>`

```
$.get('plugin.php?id=cc&do=shop', $('#jnfarm_pop').serialize(), result => {
   //alert('success');
   console.log(result); // check the result in console and if you can see it as a JS object you don't need to parse
   result = JSON.parse(result); // Parse is required if you return the result as plain text otherwise you can omit this step in case you are returning the result as content type json
   alert(result.final);//alert message here
   location.href = result.link;// if you need to get redirected

}).fail(result => {
   alert('fail');
});
```

`PHP`

```
<?php
if($_GET['id'] == 'cc'){
  if(submitcheck('shopsubmit')){ //core function in !Discuz 
    for($x=1;$x<=50;$x++){
      if($_GET['jsid'][$x] == '1'){
        $qty[$x] = intval($_GET['qty'][$x]);
        //process....
      }
    }
    $final = 'message here';
    echo json_encode(['final' => $final]);
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: In your Ajax change the method to get.php is expecting to receive get parameters and you are passing them in the url as get.

Comment: `url: $('#jnfarm_pop').attr('action'),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not initiate a direct browser redirect using server-side code on ajax request like you do with synchronous requests. instead, you have to return a URL to which you want to get redirected to and then do something like `location.href = result.link` in the result callback.

for ajax request, the simplest option is using as follows

```
$.get('plugin.php?id=cc&do=shop', $('#jnfarm_pop').serialize(), result => {
   //alert('success');
   console.log(result); // check the result in console and if you can see it as a JS object you don't need to parse
   result = JSON.parse(result); // Parse is required if you return the result as plain text otherwise you can omit this step in case you are returning the result as content type json
   let final = result.final;
   location.href = result.link;// if you need to get redirected

}).fail(result => {
   alert('fail');
});
```

now in the server-side code instead of creating a redirect from PHP return something like

```
return json_encode(['link' => 'somlink']);
```

of just return success message as usual.

Comment: Hi, after ajax submit, I just need to show a popup message like success or error. No need to redirect page again..

Comment: $.get('plugin.php?id=cc&do=shop', $('#jnfarm_pop').serialize(), (result) => {
   alert('success');
}).fail(result => {
    alert('fail');
});

updated answer

Comment: Beside that, is it available for setting Timeout? I just find out if using my popup, it will disappear very quickly..

Comment: $.get is the quickest way to accomplish your purpose $.ajax usually used when you need to have more flexibility, which is not required for your case. and I didn't get what do you mean by the disappearing of the popup. do you use js alert or using any custom popup ?

Comment: i using a custom ui it called Layui. But it is ok, now I face a last problem.. in my `plugin.php`, `<?php //much code here; $final = 'custom wording'; ?>`, how to i get this `$final` in the `(result)`?

Comment: in PHP you can do something like return json_encode(['final' => $final]);

and in ajax success, you can parse the result and get the value something like this

result = JSON.parse(result);
alert(result.final);

Comment: my php `<?php $final = 'www'; return json_encode(['final' => $final]); ?>` and I was modify my `jQuery.get` like `jQuery.get('plugin.php?id=..', jQuery('#jnfarm_pop').serialize(), (result) => {
  result = JSON.parse(result); alert(result.final);
 })` and it show js error in dev mode.. if using `jQuery.get('plugin.php?id=...', jQuery('#jnfarm_pop').serialize(), (result = JSON.parse(result)) => {
  alert(result.final);
 })` this alert show `unidentified`;.. is it any way i missed? thank you.

Comment: what error you are getting in the console ? did you try console.log the result? check my answer and try again following each step I've updated the answer a bit to make it more clear for you

Comment: change `return json_encode();` to `echo json_encode();` work fine.. since my php not in a function...

Comment: ah okay, my mistake. I said return because we usually use return in frameworks like laravel, Codeigniter, etc where we will have a response class to perform the output. so my went in that way LOL,  in plain PHP code, you need to echo instead of return. anyways glad to hear that you got it resolved.